# Perl: Copying array elements into single string

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I am trying to copy each array elements with slight modification into single string variable in Perl. What I want is to copy each element by adding 0x prefix into string. This is what I have tried so far:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my @values = (01, 02, 03, 04);
  my $res = "";
  
  foreach my $val (@values) {
    $res = join '', "0x", "$val", ", ";
  }

  print "$res\n";
 
  exit 0;
```

As a result I got just 0x04,. Wanted result should be like: 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop you overwrite the string in every iteration. That is why you only get the last value.

You can use [`join()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) over the whole array, not just the individual parts of an element. To prefix and zero pad the numbers and get their hexadecimal representation in the array you can use [`map()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`sprintf()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @values = (01, 02, 03, 04);
my $res = '';

$res = join(', ', map({ sprintf('0x%02x', $_) } @values));

print("$res\n");

exit(0);
```

(Also note, that your shebang was missing the leading forward slash (`/`). Most likely that's not intentional.)

Comment: I totally understood your code. Just one minor note: Since hex values are not only consisting of numerical values better to use %s instead of %i

Comment: The OP probably wants the hex representation of the numbers. For that, use `sprintf('0x%02x', $_)`

Comment: @Emil: If there are numbers in the array and you want the hexadecimal representation of them (which I probably should have guessed by the `0x` prefix), you can use `x` instead of `i` in `sprintf()`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @values = (01, 02, 03, 04);
my @array;

foreach my $val (@values) {
    push (@array, "0x".$val);
}

print Dumper(\@array);

my $res = join(",", @array);
print $res;
```

Comment: The OP probably wants the hex representation of the numbers. For that, use `sprintf('0x%02x', $val)`